# Novo POOL conexão no Glassfish está dando erro

Tags: glassfish

Estou tentando fazer um novo POOL de Conexão no GlassFish, mas quando vou testar no "Ping" ele apresenta o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As propriedades configuradas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode de dar uma ajuda?

Comment: esse admin@@locahost está estranho. Como está as propriedades da conexão do pool? Para não expor suas informações coloca senha e ip (se tiver) fictícios.

Comment: adicionei as propriedades na pergunta, Flávio

Comment: legal, vamos lá, você usa mesmo todas essas propriedades rs? Se não usa e já estava assim para algo básico você precisa apenas das propriedades User, Password e URL, pode apagar todas as demais. Na URL coloca o ip do banco ou localhost se for o caso `jdbc:mysql://locahost:3306/umariadb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce nao precisa de todas essas configurações.

Crie um JDBC Connection pool   no glassfish  com as configs abaixo:

> ```
> datasource-classname: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource
> res-type=javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource
> ```

Depois clique em aditional properties  e coloque essas propriedades

```
> name="User" value="NameUSER" 
> name="Password" value="yourpass"
> name="serverName" value="localhost" 
> name="databaseName" value="databasename"
```

Isto deve funcionar !